# how to watch the `ng-model` from the form element

Tags: angularjs

I am getting data from server and binding to form elements. in case of these datas are edited by the user, i would like to know the status. for that I am trying to watch the object. but i am not getting the result.

what is the correct way to watch the change from the `ng-model`?

here is my try:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.issue = {
    name:"arr",
    age:15
  };

  $scope.$watch( $scope.issue, function(nv,ov) {

    console.log(nv, ov);

  }, true)

});


 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <form action="">
      <input type="text" ng-model="issue.name">
    </form>

  </body>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgEpSUvTsXUTsSSlzXuq?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer you'll be happy to know. $watch already presume $scope as its point of watching. so you supply as the first paramter the string value of the variable on $scope you want to watch. If you change

```
$scope.$watch( $scope.issue, function(nv,ov) {
```

to

```
$scope.$watch( "issue", function(nv,ov) {
```

everything will work :)

Comment: I am trying to find the change and no-change by modifiing and reverting the text field, but i am not getting the result. can you help me to fix this? http://plnkr.co/edit/xgEpSUvTsXUTsSSlzXuq?p=preview

Comment: that's a different question, feel free to open another question if your searches return no results for an already answered question. You are moving into the realms of an ng-form. ng-form out of the box supplies a few concepts, touched/untouched fields with $dirty and $pristine, data validation checks with $error values. If you are looking to see if the value has been changed there is a lot of power in ng-form.

Comment: Also can you make your plunk public please. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.$watch('issue', function(nv,ov) {

    console.log(nv, ov);

}, true)
```